Actualizar DataSource de un DataGredView en VB.Net
me podrían decir, como actualizar un DataSource de un dataGredView.
Me explico:
Lleno un Datagredview con los datos de un Excel a través de una DataTable.
Añado unas columnas al Datagredview y en esas columnas le añado datos.
El problema es que si hago:
Dim dt As New DataTable

dt = TryCast(MiDatagredview.DataSource, DataTable)

Obtengo solo los datos cargados inicialmente, los que he añadido yo no están.
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.
